# SQL sentence only takes id's of less than 6 digits MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to understand why this is happening but I couldn't find anything in the internet.
I have a table of meds(called Medicamento) which has 23600 elements in it.
When I try to take an element using the IdMed column it only takes the values with less than 6 digits. 
Example 1:

```
SELECT * FROM `Medicamento` WHERE IdMed=100
```

[image]

Example 2:

```
SELECT * FROM `Medicamento` WHERE IdMed=200703
```

[image]

At this point I thought that the med with that Id was not created so I did this last query which made me not knowing where the mistake is:

```
SELECT * FROM `Medicamento` WHERE IdMed>200702
```

Result:
[image]

As you can see the first element is the one with the 200703 Id. What I cannot understand is why it takes elemnts with Id's such as 12700 or 100 but it doesn't take elements with Id's of 6 numbers. I thought it could be a matter of formats but I didn't find anything helpful.

Data of the table was taken from 2 different .xlsx files, that's why I thought about formats.

PD: Sorry for my bad English. I hope the problem is understood.

EDIT:
Table data types
[image]

Comment: what's your data structure look like for the table...notably the column in question

Comment: Check the question again, I've edited it

Comment: What's the table definition?

Comment: you should use INT data type for the ID and not FLOAT. See [this](https://code.rohitink.com/2013/06/12/mysql-integer-float-decimal-data-types-differences/) for the main differences between the two data types.

Comment: I'm not overly familiar with MySQL in particular, but it's probably because your data type is `float` not some sort of integer type.  Edit: Ninja'ed by 8 seconds.

Comment: If you mean what is the table about is medicines. IdMed would be the id of the medicine, Precio would be the price of this and Nombre is the description of it. I don't know if you meant this, my English is pretty rusted.

Comment: The problem here is that I'm using Id codes which are like 200000.5 so, should I create another column for id and make IdMed unique?

Comment: Without seeing the images (blocked at work) and table's structure, I would say that your column is declared as INT(5) and thus only stores 5-digits numbers.

Comment: also, check that you don't have any extra char in the field. Edit that specific field to see and repeat the query. It can be a carriage return or things like that that are not displayed but will affect query result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a nutshell, what's happening is your value is losing precision because you're using an inaccurate data type.  `float` is for floating point numbers, and ideally shouldn't normally be used as a primary key.  your best bet is to change this to an `integer` data type instead.  By the looks of the comments, this may not be viable, you're probably best off to create another column and use THAT as the primary key instead.  What's likely happening is for example with `200703`, it's potentially being stored in the database as `200703.000001` or `2007002.99999` and you're searching for a value that's not an exact match to how the database is storing it.

As a suggestion, you may want to change your current `float` column to a `double` column instead to retain a little more precision beyond the decimal point.